# Cannot run Cypher query

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql

I have to do that:Find the students who are over 22 years old and are studying Databases. Expected result:

```
MATCH (p:Student)-[:Study]->(s:Subject)
WHERE p.age > 22 AND s.name = “Databases” 
RETURN p
```

```
Invalid input '“': expected whitespace, comment or an expression (line 2, column 31 (offset: 70))
"WHERE p.age > 22 AND s.name = “Databases”"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong double quotes (“ instead of ").
The query should be:

```
MATCH (p:Student)-[:Study]->(s:Subject)
WHERE p.age > 22 AND s.name = "Databases"
RETURN p
```

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as the accepted solution, then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes

```
MATCH (p:Student)-[:Study]->(s:Subject)
WHERE p.age > 22 AND s.name = 'Databases' 
RETURN p
```